# $http.get returns Html code in response instead of json object

Tags: json, angularjs, http-get

I'm trying to get some data from an external API using angular $http.get method , but i'm getting 'html code' instead of 'json object' in response. When i tried calling the API using jquery ajax it worked fine. Here's the code

```
  $http.get({
   "url": 'https://ebaydemo.stamplayapp.com/api/cobject/v1/projects',
   "crossDomain": true,
   "headers": {
      "accept": "application/json",
      "content-type": "application/json"
    },
    "params": {
      "populate": false,
      "n": 10
    },
    "processData": false
  }).success(function (response) {
   console.log(response);// Response has 'html code'
  });
```

**Edit**
Here's the short snippet of response i'm getting now:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]--   >
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<base href="/">
<title></title>
```

Comment: Whats html response?

Comment: Shouldn't content-type be 'json' and not 'application/json'?

Comment: More information please, in other case we cant help...

Comment: @EmirMarques Hi, as the response is big, i'm pasting a short snippet of it. 

<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <base href="/">
    <title></title>

Comment: @IsmaelFuentes Added sample response in the edit. Please have a look

Comment: @EmirMarques Added sample response in the edit. Please have a look

Comment: Pasting the url in the browser returns JSON so it seems strange it would return HTML.

Comment: Try set "content-type": "application/json" as "Content-type": "application/json"

Comment: @EmirMarques Didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a little HTML snippet to call your code like below:

```
<html>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="eBayController">
<input type="button" value="EBay" ng-click="getFromEbay()"></input>
<script rc="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="ebay.js"></script>
</body>
```

and then just reduced the JavaScript to this:

```
/* global angular */
angular.module("app",[])
.controller('eBayController', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.getFromEbay = function() {
        $http.get("https://ebaydemo.stamplayapp.com/api/cobject/v1/projects")
        .success(function (response) 
        {
            console.log(response);
        }); 
   }
```

})

and I'm getting a JSON object back.

Comment: I'm getting 404 error on this. 
GET https://ebaydemo.stamplayapp.com/api/cobject/v1/projects 404 (OK)

Comment: That's very odd. I'm not. I get 20 items back.

Comment: Yeah, its strange that it works perfectly with jquery ajax

Comment: You may want to try disabling any browser plug-ins you have enabled.

Comment: I have one avast antivirus plugin. Disabled it, but didn't work

Comment: What Browser are you using? I'm using Chrome and it's working fine. When I tried to open https://ebaydemo.stamplayapp.com/api/cobject/v1/projects in IE it launched Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I'm using chrome. Also, i've a sample application generated using yeoman full stack generator. I'm running the code inside of the same application. Would there be any issue ?

Comment: Hard to say without really seeing all of it. If you trace the code does the call to $http.get actually step into angular? (I'm wondering is some other library has redefined $http). If you try the little sample I posted standalone, does it work?

Comment: Yes, while testing as a standalone app, it works. So i think there is some kind of conflict in my application.

Comment: Cool. I'd guess that $http is getting redefned somewhere or perhaps even just its get method. (Oh, and I'd accept my answer then too. :) )

Answer (score 0):

Your request is in a wrong format. Here is a plunker where you can see how it works.

http://plnkr.co/edit/QFCs8kiPvcErmeRePBMd

Take a look at `app.js` and how the `$http` is being used

Comment: I'm getting 404 error on this. GET ebaydemo.stamplayapp.com/api/cobject/v1/projects 404 (OK)

Comment: Which browser are you using?